# Работа с фото-камерой в iOS квадратная съемка

Tags: objective-c, камера, ios

Доброе время суток, подскажите пожалуйста как открытькамеру из приложения в режиме фотографии квадратом, ниже фотка: (фильтров не нужно)

[image]

На данный момент камуру открываю так:

```
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
        [imagePickerController setDelegate:self];
        imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage,nil];

        imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePickerController.allowsEditing = NO;

        popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController];
        [popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:self.imageViewuserPhoto.bounds inView:self.imageViewuserPhoto permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
    else {            
//на устройстве нет камеры
    }
```

Буду очень благодарен за помощь :)

Comment: Ребят, неужели никто не силен в этом вопросе?

Comment: imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES; вроде как и вернет вам квадрат

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, условие на существование камеры лишние, но думаю вам будет полезно прочитать.
[тык](http://blog.denivip.ru/index.php/2012/07/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-apple-ios/)